# framer-motion - dom node does not unmounts immediately after exit animation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I have created an animated modal container
it's working fine for the most part
the only issue is after doing the exit animation it takes a second or two to unmount (in that period cannot click anywhere else)

code sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-platform-oovo1?file=/src/App.js

To see the issue

- click show modal button
- Click anywhere to close the modal
- *notice that the scrollbar still exist denoting modal is not unmounted*
- **Also, you cannot reopen modal immediately on clicking of the open modal button after exit animation (for that 1 sec)**

I had seen `safeToremove` but didn't understand how to use it as there is no proper documentation

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the documentation is a little frustrating where this is concerned - here's what I've learned through playing around with it.

The documentation shows the code for usePresence() within the presence component to be:

```
import { usePresence } from "framer-motion"

export const Component = () => {
  const [isPresent, safeToRemove] = usePresence()

  useEffect(() => {
    !isPresent && setTimeout(safeToRemove, 1000)
  }, [isPresent])

  return <div />
}
```

This initially seemed arbitrary/purely an example. However, after playing around with it, it turns out that if you initialize usePresence(), **this useEffect code is now necessary for the presence to work correctly and in part determining the functionality of the presence.** Try initializing usePresence and then commenting out the line

```
// !isPresent && setTimeout(safeToRemove, 1000)
```

It will break your animate presence.

So the setTimeout function wrapping **safeToRemove** is, in fact, determining core functionality of the AnimatePresence and able to determine the timing of the virtual DOM becoming clickable again, etc.

Now, I was playing around with the crossfade AnimateSharedLayout, so it was a little weird to be messing with the **safeToRemove** timing when I wasn't determining the animations themselves, but if you are setting up the animations for the modal yourself, I think that if you sync the time in that **setTimeout** function with the length of your animations, it should solve your problem.

I'm still trying to figure out exactly how all this works, so comment back and let me know what you find and we'll be one step closer to mastering using Framer v2's newest tools.